# Can I have a user in two different Linux distributions (with KDM) use the same home folder without mucking things up?

Tags: linux, dual-boot

I am planning to install two different Linux distributions on my computer, both running KDE, albeit different versions

They will both have one user `nacho`. I want both of them to use the same `/home/nacho` partition/folder.

Since both distributions will have different packages/configurations, if the user account in both distributions points to the same folder, I assume it might create issues. Especially with folders like these because they will have settings unique to one distro but both distros will read/use it:

- `.cache`
- `.config`
- `.gnome`
- `.local`

So I am wondering, is there a way to have them both use unique folders for the above? Maybe something like:

- `.distro1/.cache`
- `.distro2/.cache`
- `.distro1/.config`
- `.distro2/.config`
- `.distro1/.gnome`
- `.distro2/.gnome`
- `.distro1/.local`
- `.distro2/.local`

Is this possible?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: May I suggest you rather use a lage `/data`-partition for shared files and smaller, separate `/home`s for config files? I tried your approach one - it was a mess.

Comment: @jsotola Cause I want to bounce between two distros but share things like Documents, Downloads, etc.

Comment: @FelixJN Oh? Mind sharing more about your experience?

Comment: this site is not an experience sharing forum ... it is question and answer site for answering focused questions

Comment: like @FelixJN says, create a separate partition for file sharing